# Map displaying many measures

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to create a SSRS report with many measures in a map.

For example, how do I display Total sales in colour and Prices in bullets?

Comment: It may help if you provide an image of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a map component to SSRS, but you'll need a spatial data set that defines the points or shapes you want your measures mapping to. There are a bunch of US-centric ones it comes with, and maybe a world one at the country level.

I'm not sure about how much information you could put on the annotations, but you can also combine traditional reporting techniques with the map and have a side bar with your metrics.

One caveat, I think the maximum size of the map component is 36 inches (last time I used it anyways), if you're looking for larger you'll likely need to use some GIS software instead.

Comment: Thank U for your answer. So Can i analyse more than 1 metric ? How can I make it ?

Comment: Here's a good example of the basics:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/creating-map-drill-down-reports-in-ssrs-sql-server-2008-r2.html

Some examples of ways to show your metrics are a color scale for the geography, the data label for the geography, and what shows up in the mouse hover. For my own purposes that wasn't sufficient (as I was creating the map for print), so I went with an additional report on the side that had more metrics for each geographical region.

Comment: Thank U Kevin for your link. Very interesting.Do U have example with the side bar which displaying the another metrics ?

Comment: I can't easily post a code example here, due to the verbosity of SSRS .rdl files (a simple example runs over 2000 lines). It is literally as easy as placing a table or matrix component beside the map in the report though, they can both run off of the same dataset.